# Does the "Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum" warning message affect my unsupervised classification results?

Tags: land-classification

A similar version of this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382681/kmeans-quick-transfer-stage-steps-exceeded-maximum), but there was no satisfying answer yet.

I get the following warning for some of my satellite images: `Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (=5000000)`.

How do people usually deal with this warning?

(I am using the `unsuperClass` function from the RStoolbox package.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Oct 5, 2018 the package author has fixed this bug in the github version which can be installed using devtools "install_github" function. If that occurs the warning now says "The Harian-Wong algorithm doesn't converge properly.
Consider setting algorithm to 'Lloyd' or 'MacQueen' and/or increase nStarts," and the ["$model$ifault" will be equal to 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382681/kmeans-quick-transfer-stage-steps-exceeded-maximum).